# Relation for articles and tags with TypeORM in NestJS

Tags: sql, relationship, nestjs, typeorm

I'm actually creating an article system with associated tags by creating a relation table with the article ID and the tag ID.

The problem is that the relation is done for the first tag and not for the others and I have no idea of how to do this.

First, I'm receiving the tags as an array in the articles create DTO

```
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { IsNotEmpty } from 'class-validator';

export class CreateArticleDto {
    @ApiProperty()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    title: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    content: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    author: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    tags: Array<number>;

    @ApiProperty({ type: 'string', format: 'binary' })
    image: string;
}
```

Then, I create the relation in the articles module

```
@ManyToMany(() => TagsEntity)
@JoinTable({
  name: 'article_tags',
  joinColumn: {
    name: 'articleId',
    referencedColumnName: 'id',
  },
  inverseJoinColumn: {
    name: 'tagId',
    referencedColumnName: 'id',
  },
})
tags: TagsEntity[];
```

Moreover, here is my service for articles when I create the article

```
async createArticle(articleDto: CreateArticleDto) {
    const readingTime = Utils.estimateReadingTime(articleDto.content);
    const slug: string = Utils.slugify(articleDto.title);
    const tags: TagsEntity[] = await this.tagsRepository.findByIds(articleDto.tags);
    const articleEntity: ArticlesEntity = await this.articlesRepository.create({
      ...articleDto,
      readingTime,
      tags,
      slug,
    });

    return this.articlesRepository.save(articleEntity);
  }
```

The result is that if I try to create an article with 3 tags (id 1, id 2, id 3), there is only the article ID 1 with the tag ID 1 and not the tag ID 2 and 3 instead of having the article ID 1 three times with each tag ID.

Comment: Can you share the code of the service? how you store the article with tags?

Comment: I added it to the post @Youba

Comment: Your code seems to work properly, I'm afraid of the tags array doesn't get from the source, Can you show me the array format that the backend got from you Frontend or postman?

Comment: I'm using swagger by sending an array of IDs (number) corresponding to existing tags

Comment: Can you log the `articleDto.tags` and share the result?

Comment: I'm receiving 2,3,4 if I send 2, 3 and 4 in swagger

Comment: that's the problem you're not sending array in the format the service wait for

Comment: Check the update of my answer

Comment: did you take a look at the updated answer?

Comment: Yes I answered to it

Answer (score 0):

Till you can share the code of your service, I've tried with the same entities and DTo you've used and I added all the tags without any problem: here is my create function :

```
async  create(createArticleDto: CreateArticleDto) {
 const article = new Article();
 article.title = createArticleDto.title;
 ...
 const tags: Tag[] = await this.tagRepository.findByIds(createArticleDto.tags);
   article.tags = tags;
return await this.articleRepository.save(article);
```

}

**UPDATE**

After you comment, the problem is in the format fo the array you send to the Ws
I think you're sending the array this way [tags]: 1,2,3

[image]

Instead, the way you should to send the array is:

```
tags[] : 1
tags[] : 2
tags[] : 4
```

[image]

Comment: I need to send an unique array containing all the IDs and not an array of Objects containing the IDs

Comment: glad that works for you, thanks to accepting this answer

Comment: This doesn't work, you gave me a solution with an array of Objects containing IDs but I need to send an array of IDs as numbers (int)

Comment: I think you didn't understand the syntax, as you see here `tags[] : 1
tags[] : 2
tags[] : 4` this's just a way to send a simple array that's I sent  to test, it's all about syntax

Comment: Yes that's a way to send an array but I need to send the array this way [tags]: 1,2,3 as Swagger do when the type Array<number> is defined